# Meta analyses on vegetarian diet

Tags: diet, lasting-effects-duration, risks, vegetarianism, vegan

I am looking for long or short term study (preferably meta analysis) about effects of vegetarian or vegan diet on mortality, cardiovascular risks and cancer risks.

Answer (score 2):

Links:

[2016 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26853923)

[2014 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24566947)

They are both meta analysis. Long term effects though.

Comment: However, be aware that some critique that the relationship between plant-based diets and low risk of certain cancers is due to the fact that vegans and vegetarians tend to be more health conscious (ex. don't smoke, do more exercise) than meat eaters. Some studies have tried to take these factors into account and they still find a correlation.

Comment: Just a link is insufficient as an answer. Could I ask you to summarise the findings of both meta analyses? Otherwise, this is in danger of being removed by mods as link-only answers are not tolerated.